# C Empty Struct Pointer on Stack

Tags: c, pointers, struct, declaration, compound-literals

I would like to initialize a struct with all fields as zero and immediately assign it to a pointer. The struct will only need to be used within static functions whose lifetime is completely contained within the calling function.

This is the line I currently have

```
move_stats *mv_s = (move_stats *){0};
```

The struct is defined in a header file as

```
typedef struct {
  byte open_threes;
  byte open_fours;
  byte half_open_fours;
  bool overline;
  bool five;
} move_stats;
```

`byte` is an alias for unsigned char.
Will this create the struct in the way I want it to as written? I could not find a question exactly like this, apologies if it is a duplicate.

Comment: Use  *compound literals*: `move_stats *mv_s = &(move_stats){0};`

Comment: Thanks. I knew casting to pointer didn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compound ;literal defines a null pointer instead of an object of the structure type

```
move_stats *mv_s = (move_stats *){0};
```

Instead write

```
move_stats *mv_s = &(move_stats){0};
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can call `(move_stats *){0}` a compound literal. It is just casting `0` to a pointer.

Comment: This gives you a dangling pointer, as the compound literal's lifetime ends at the end of the  declaration.

Comment: @ChrisDodd You are wring.

Comment: @ChrisDodd No. Compound literal, when in a function scope, has the same life time as any local variable.

Comment: @EugeneSh. There is neither casting. There is a definition of a compound literal.

Comment: Oh well, it is falling under the definition of compound literal as written.